# Unity custom inspector which allows selected child objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a custom inspector for a `PlayerInventory` class.  The `PlayerInventory` class consists of a list of items (which are `ScriptableObjects`), along with a quantity of each item, like this:

```
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
   public string description;
   public Sprite picture;
}

public class InventoryItem : ScriptableObject
{
   // A reference to the Item object that contains the item's description, 
   // picture, stats, etc.
   public Item item;

   // The quantity of this item that the player has in his inventory
   public int quantity;
}

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Player/Player Inventory")]
public class PlayerInventory : ScriptableObject
{
   // The list of each distinct item that the player has in his inventory,
   // along with the quantity of each item
   public List<InventoryItem> items;
}
```

I created an instance of `PlayerInventory` as a game asset.  By default, the Inspector shows a list of `InventoryItem`s.  However, what I want is for the Inspector to show each `InventoryItem` element with a field to select an `Item` for it, a field to enter a quantity, and a "delete" button.

Here's a visual example of what I'm trying to achieve, along with my current code below.  The problem with this screenshot is that Unity is making me select an `InventoryItem` object for each element.  I want to be able to select an `Item` object for each element.  The second problem I'm having is I don't know how to set an `EditorGUILayout.TextField` to the `InventoryItem.quantity` property because I don't know how to convert the `SerializedProperty` to an `InventoryItem` object.

[image]

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(PlayerInventory))]
public class PlayerInventoryEditor : Editor
{
   public override void OnInspectorGUI()
   {
       this.serializedObject.Update();

       SerializedProperty items = this.serializedObject.FindProperty("items");
       for (int i = 0; i < items.arraySize; i++)
       {
           EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
           EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Item", GUILayout.Width(50));

           // I don't know how to make this line reference the child "item"
           // field of the current InventoryItem
           EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(items.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i), GUIContent.none, GUILayout.Width(170));

           EditorGUILayout.LabelField("    Quantity", GUILayout.Width(80));

           // I don't know how to set the text field to the "quantity" field
           // of the current InventoryItem
           EditorGUILayout.TextField("0", GUILayout.Width(50));

           EditorGUILayout.LabelField("", GUILayout.Width(20));
           GUILayout.Button("Delete Item");               
           EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
       }

       GUILayout.Button("Add Item");
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried making `InventoryItem` now inherit from `ScriptableObject`, and now the Inspector works like I expect it to, and lets me show the `item` field.  What is it about `ScriptableObject` that causes the inspector to work differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes must be serializable to appear in the Inspector. See [Serializable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html)

**Edit**. Following further discussion in the comments below, here's the full snippet;

Standard class marked `Serializable`;

```
[System.Serializable]
public class InventoryItem
{
    public Item item;
    public int quantity;
}
```

With PlayerInventoryEditor;

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI ()
{
    this.serializedObject.Update();

    SerializedProperty items = this.serializedObject.FindProperty("items");

    for (int i = 0; i < items.arraySize; i++)
    {
        SerializedProperty item = items.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Item", GUILayout.Width(50));
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(item.FindPropertyRelative("item"), GUIContent.none, GUILayout.Width(170));
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("    Quantity", GUILayout.Width(80));
        EditorGUILayout.IntField(item.FindPropertyRelative("quantity").intValue, GUILayout.Width(50));

        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("", GUILayout.Width(20));
        GUILayout.Button("Delete Item");
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }

    GUILayout.Button("Add Item");
}
```

Comment: Aren't `ScriptableObject`s serializable by default?

Comment: Yes, Unity Objects are serialisable by default. Your original code did not override `ScriptableObject` and was not marked `serializable` as per my answer which is what caused the original issue. (Sorry, there was a delay between reading your question and sending the answer so I missed the edit) :)

Comment: Sorry about that edit.  I was typing my code into the post, and I forgot to put the inheritance from `ScriptableObject` in there.  It seems like inheriting from `ScriptableObject` causes the Inspector to act differently than if the class is just serializable and not inherited from `ScriptableObject`

Comment: No problem Ben - it was my bad for not checking the question again. :)

Comment: The Inspector is acting differently because a standard class (not inherited from `MonoBehaviour/ScriptableObject`) has no default property field like a SO asset file. Nevertheless, functionality-wise it works as equally well with a standard class marked `serializable` as it does with a class inheriting from SO. I've checked this for sanity and it appears to be the case. Since I've typed it up (and without meaning to replicate @nipercop's excellent answer) I will update my answer for completeness/clarity...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FindPropertyRelative`

```
//...
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(
    items.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).FindPropertyRelative("item"),
    new GUIContent("Item"), 
    GUILayout.Width(170));
//...
```

And same method for your 'Quantity' field.

Make sure InventoryItem not `null` in your items List.